# PHP Code with HTML

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am creating a simple MVC site that uses CRUD. For the delete function I have a button, the code below is what I am trying to use to send the rowID to the controller to handle.

I am having trouble in that the code doesnt print out on the screen correctly, The php code is being printed as well as the button.

The rowID isnt being passed either and I am wondering if my approach with the php code is the correct way?

**Code**

```
<?php
$itemsDAO = new ItemsDAO();
$result=$itemsDAO->getItems();
foreach ( $result as $row )  {
    $uid = $row['id'];
    var_dump($uid);
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteItem' />
<p>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" id="fId" name="fId" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Delete">
    </div>
</div>
</p>
</fieldset>
 </form>

 <?php } ?>
```

**Delete Function**

```
    public function getItems () {
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT *";
    $sqlQuery .= " FROM items";

    $result = $this->getDbManager()->executeSelectQuery($sqlQuery );
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo $uid; ?>"` Besides, you're overwriting $uid and printing that only once. Not sure if that's exactly what you want to do. It is mandatory to firstly understand what you want to do and how you want to do that. Your code, in my opinion, does not truly represent what you want to do.

Comment: I am still in the learning process with all this, I was trying to make it loop for each row

Comment: Check your code: you are setting to an undeclared variable ($uid) a value of a row, but the foreach is repeated BEFORE you're actually printing it. If you closely check the logic of your code, you will find out that you will print only ONE row, which will be the very last entry of your $result array. Check @Blowski's solution below and find the difference! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a string replace in you forloop if you have one.

I think it would look something like this

```
foreach ( $this->model->itemList as $row ) 
            $HTMLItemList .= "<li><strong>" . $row ["title"] . ": </strong>" . $row ["price"] . "<blockquote>" . 
                $row ["description"] .  " " . str_replace("value2replace", $row['id'], $buttons) . ""  . $update . "</blockquote></li>";
```

And then you would change your form to the following

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteItem' />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="hidden" id="fId" name="fId"
                value="value2replace"> <input type="submit"
                class="btn btn-success" value="Delete" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a delete form for each and every result, you need to wrap the HTML inside the `foreach` statement:

```
<?php
$result=$itemsDAO->getItems();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $uid = $row['id'];
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input id='action' type='hidden' name='action' value='deleteItem' />
    <p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="hidden" id="fID" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Delete">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was very helpful, I didnt know i needed to end the loop like you did with `<?php } ?>`, do you know why it i still printing the php code?

Comment: Ca you see why the `$results` isnt receiving a value? I have added the delete function I am using in the itemsDAO

Comment: @patrick Check that the `getItems()` method is returning something. Perhaps the `getDbManager()` method is returning `null`, or perhaps the `executeSelectQuery()` method. The answer to this could be one of many, many things. Isolate your development to fixing the `getItems()` method, ensure you're outputting all errors (either to screen or to logs). Personally, I might consider using a framework like Laravel or Yii to help you along at this stage.